# How to change image source in JavaScript through the array?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have a grid with an template column and in that column I have text and icon,
on icon mousehover (on mode) and mousehoverout (off mode) I am changing the icon.

Now when the user click on icon it opens a  popup and the icon must be in "On" mode but if the user without closing clicks another row's icon then previous must be in off and current should be in on mode.

So for that I have written this:

```
<DataItemTemplate>
    <div class="floatLeft titleBlock">
                        <a href="<%# Eval("Link") %>" class="ellipsesTooltip"><span>
                            <%# Container.Text%></span><%# Container.Text%></a></div>
                    <div class="floatRight">
                        <a onclick="GridValueCatcherMoreLike(this, '<%# Eval("ResearchNoteId").ToString()%>');">
                            <img alt="+/- 30 days matching Author, Industry, Theme" src="../Image/Research/MoreByOff.gif" onClick="check(this,'../Image/Research/MoreByOn.gif', '../Image/Research/MoreByOn.gif');"
                                onmouseover="ToggleAuthorMoreLikeImage(this, 'MoreLikePopUp', '../Image/Research/MoreByOn.gif', '../Image/Research/MoreByOff.gif');"
                                onmouseout="ToggleAuthorMoreLikeImage(this, 'MoreLikePopUp', '../Image/Research/MoreByOff.gif', '../Image/Research/MoreByOff.gif');" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

```
function check(sender, onImg, offImg) {   
    debugger;
    for(var i=0;i<activeImgList.length;i++)
    {        
        if(sender!=activeImgList[i])
            activeImgList[i].scr = offImage;   
        else     
            activeImgList[i].scr = onImg;
    } 
    return true;
}



function ToggleAuthorMoreLikeImage(sender, popupname, imageurl, offImageurl)
{
    var win = ResearchPopup.GetWindowByName(popupname);
    if (!ResearchPopup.IsWindowVisible(win))
    {        
        sender.src=imageurl;
        activeImgList[arrayIndex]=sender;
        arrayIndex = arrayIndex + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        activeImgList[arrayIndex] = sender;
        arrayIndex = arrayIndex + 1;   
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the resulting HTML code? (View source in browser.)

Comment: Do you use the same on/off images for all the icons?

Comment: Not all the code is here in order to run this and it's not immediately obvious where the problem is (except that you miss-spelled `onmouseout`) - in what way does this not work?

Comment: @rorfy: No roy that spelling mistak is happen when i was trying format text in stackoverflow, but in code it is not there? All javascript event are running fine i have checked by debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a step back and use something like [jQuery.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) or [jQuery.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) on the client side?

**.hover()**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  ul { margin-left:20px; color:blue; }
  li { cursor:default; }
  span { color:red; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Bread</li>
    <li class='fade'>Chips</li>

    <li class='fade'>Socks</li>
  </ul>
<script>
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
  }
);   

//li with fade class
$("li.fade").hover(function(){$(this).fadeOut(100);$(this).fadeIn(500);});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**.toggleClass()**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

  p { margin: 4px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bolder; 
      cursor:pointer; }
  .blue { color:blue; }
  .highlight { background:yellow; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="blue">Click to toggle</p>
  <p class="blue highlight">highlight</p>
  <p class="blue">on these</p>
  <p class="blue">paragraphs</p>
<script>
    $("p").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```